# compact set under two topological

Tags: general-topology

Let $\Omega_1\subset\Omega_2$ be two topological structures in $X$.Does the compactness of $(X,\Omega_2)$ imply that of $(X,\Omega_1)$,or vice versa?

Since there are more open sets in $\Omega_2$ than that in $\Omega_1$,so I think the compactness of $(X,\Omega_1)$ imply that of $(X,\Omega_2)$,is it right?

Comment: It is the other way around compactness of $(X,\Omega_2)$ implies $(X,\Omega_1)$ is compact.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\Omega_1$ to be the standard topology on $[0,1]$ and $\Omega_2$ is the discrete topology  on $[0,1]$. It is known that $[0,1]$ under $\Omega_1$ is compact, but $[0,1] = \cup_{x\in[0,1]} \{x\}$ is an open cover of $[0,1]$ for $\Omega_2$, and does not admit a finite subcover hence $[0,1]$ is not compact for the discrete topology.

It works the other way around: suppose $X$ is compact for $\Omega_2$. Let $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ be a cover of $X$ with opens from $\Omega_1$. All $U_i$'s are opens of $\Omega_2$, hence you can get a finite subcover as per the compactness of $X$, hence $X$ is still compact under $\Omega_1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(U_i)$ is an open cover of $(X,\Omega_1)$, then it's also an open cover of $(X,\Omega_2)$, hence admits a finite subcover.

Comment: Your answer is opposite to the comment above.

Comment: No, this answer is exactly the same as the comment by @azarel. See my answer for details.